# WCF Service request rejected even though user is part of the ActiveDirectory security group

Tags: wcf, iis, active-directory

We developed a WCF service hosted by IIS 7.5. To manage access to the service, we created an Active Directory security group. Our regional settings are U.S. When a Korean colleague attempts to access the service, even though he is a member of the AD security group, our code rejects him. When he does a command prompt whoami/groups, the security group appears, but instead of a "\" character between the domain and username, we see a funny-looking "W". When he temporarily changes his regional settings to U.S., no change occurs - the service still rejects him. We tried this from a VM in China with Korean usercode and the service accepted the request. Anyone have a direction to try to debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem had nothing to do with authentication. The code on the server is a mixed-mode application. The unmanaged code tries to write a file and the server does not allow this unless the directory where the file will be written has the proper permissions. Ours did not.